# CodenameOne Background color

Tags: background-color, codenameone

I've got a problem setting background color of a TextField:

```
private TextField mValueField;

public void setFgColor(int color) {
    mValueField.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0xFF);

    if (color == Controller.WHITE_COLOR) {
        mValueField.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xFFFFFF);
    } else if (color == Controller.RED_COLOR) {
        mValueField.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xFF0000);
    }
}
```

The first call sets white color, subsequent calls set white or red color but the TextField's background remains white all the time. If i change the color of the first call to red then the TextField's background color becomes red but also never changes if setting to white later-on.

Answer (score 1):

After changing the bg color, you should immediately call `mValueField.getComponentForm().repaint();` or `mValueField.getParent().repaint();`

Comment: I'd also add that since the text field has a border a color background will not make a difference. So `mValueField.getAllStyles().setBorder(null)` would set the color but it's probably not the "right way"... I would suggest using `setUIID("TextFieldInvalid")` and styling that. Which seems to be what he is trying to do